# Pandas: How To Select Neighboring Rows Based on Rank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like so (`csv` format, the first row is the header):

```
employee_id, workplace, rank
1, google, 1
1, facebook, 2
1, apple, 3
2, amazon, 1
2, google, 2
2, netflix, 3
```

1. `employee_id`: represents a unique employee ID
2. `workplace`: represents
   a workplace of the employee at some point in time
3. `rank`: represents **when** the employee worked there - for example, "1" means that they
   currently work there. "2" means that it's their previous workplace. "3" is where they had worked before working at "2". etc.

My goal is to find out where did Google employees work prior to working at Google (the **immediate** previous workplace)?

For example, the output would be (`csv` format, the first row is the header):

```
first_previous_workplace_for_googlers
facebook
netflix
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assume your dataframe is already sorted by `rank`:

```
first_previous_workplace = lambda x: x.eq('google').shift(fill_value=False)
out = df[df.groupby('employee_id')['workplace'].apply(first_previous_workplace)]
print(out)

# Output
   employee_id workplace  rank
1            1  facebook     2
5            2   netflix     3
```